# HTTP responseError interceptor causing $http error callback to not being called when testing with $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am testing an angular service method with $httpBackend and trying to mock different responses based on the request data. The problem is, if I send the error status if request is invalid, it still calls the success callback of $http method, thus I am not able to test the error situation. Below is the service:

```
app.service('dataService', function($http) {
    var self = this;
    this.getData = function (request) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://some-url/',
            data: request
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            self.valid = true;
            self.data = response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            self.valid = false
        });
    };
});
```

And below is the test code:

```
describe('.getData()', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function(_dataService_, _$httpBackend_) {
        var dataService = _dataService_,
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $httpBackend.when('POST', 'http://some-url/', 'valid request')
            .respond(200, 'data');
        $httpBackend.when('POST', 'http://some-url/', 'invalid request')
            .respond(500, '');
    }));

    // runs successfully
    it('should store data correctly', function() {
        dataService.getData('valid request').then(
            function success(){
                expect(dataService.data).toEqual('data');
            }
        );
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });

    // TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    // This error comes in service at successCallBack() line "self.data = response.data;"
    it('should result in error if any', function() {
        dataService.getData('invalid request').then(
            function success(){
                expect(dataService.valid).toEqual(false);
            }
        );
        $httpBackend.flush();        
    });
});
```

As I analyzed, this is happening because of the HTTP responseError interceptor. If I remove the interceptor, then the test code works fine (success and error callbacks are called correctly based on response status). But as soon as I use `responseError` interceptor, it kind of 'swallows' the error and causes `successCallback()` to be called, and sets `response` as `undefined` inside success callback.

What is the solution in this case? How can we test success and error situations in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I was not returning the rejection from the `responseError` HTTP interceptor. Returning the rejection (`return $q.reject('Error')`) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to lookup on the respond method signature in the official doc.
It says **respond** expects an argument of type [function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) that returns an array:

```
  $httpBackend.whenRoute('GET', '/users/:id')
  .respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params) {
    return [200, MockUserList[Number(params.id)]];
  });
```

In this piece of code, I return a success, but I think the same is true for error(500):

> ```
> ...  
>  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (ApprovalRule, $httpBackend, $http) {
>         ...
>         this.withOKEntities = function() {
>                 var i1 = new ApprovalRule();
>                 i1.id = 10;
>                 return [200, JSON.stringify([ i1]), {}];
>         } ...
>     }));
> ...
> it('should resolve to list of approvalrules', function () {
>             this.httpBackend.whenGET(new RegExp('.*/api/approvalrules/')).respond(this.withOKEntities);
>             var result = this.sut.getAll();
>             result.then(this.OnResponse.readResult);
>             this.httpBackend.flush();
>             expect(check.array.of.instance(this.OnResponse.result, this.ApprovalRule)).toBe(true);
>         });
> ```